# Finding A Good Prose Edda and other resources for Norse mythology

Tags: norse

I am beginning an interest in Norse mythology, and I am looking for a complete copy of the Prose Edda. There are several versions available on Barnes and Noble, but I want one that gives all four books, and is as close to the original as possible.

Also, if there are other texts that I should consider in conjunction with the Edda, I would like to know these also. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 4):

The *Prose Edda* translation Anthony Faulkes seems to be quite complete, it contains *Háttatal* too (this is the enumeration of verse forms omitted in several other translations). 
If you are interested in Old Norse mythology, I would recommend the following sources:

- *The Poetic Edda* (this really is one of the most important sources for our knowledge of Old Norse mythology)
- The *Völsunga Saga* (this is more about heroes than about Gods, the material overlaps in part with the Poetic Edda, the Old High German Niebelungenlied and other materials)
- *Þiðreks saga* can also be interesting, it is a heroic saga about the Gothic king Theodoric the Great who also plays a role in the *Völsunga Saga* and related texts, there are also some connections with Völundr (who is also in the *Poetic Edda*)
- The *Hervarar Saga og Heiðreks* and other saga’s, which are mostly about heroes
- the first books of the *Gesta Danorum* (a history of Denmark, originally written in Latin, but the first parts are set in mythological times and relate of Othinus/Odin, Balderus/Baldr, Hotherus/Höðr, Ollerus/Ullr and Horwendillus/Aurvandill; it offers a very different version of several stories known from other sources)
- the prologue of *Sörla þáttr*, about Freya sleeping with four dwarfs to acquire a necklace, which is then stolen by Loki